# How does one open directly into an Outlook Personal Folder (.pst folder) from the command line

Tags: command-line-interface, outlook

I have tried the /select switch with no success.  The standard outlook folders work okay (/select outlook:inbox) but how does one reference a pst folder?

Thanks in advance,

Craig

Comment: I'm wondering if the stackoverflow folks may have more experience with this?

Comment: Superuser is probably the more appropriate place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Enable the Web tool bar.
- Browse to the folder you wish to start Outlook to
- Copy the address you see and use that with the /select argument.

So Within my Outlook profile I have a set a PST which has the name **PT** and a folder named **ASDF**.  The command line I use to start outlook to the ASDF folder is **outlook.exe /select outlook:\PF\ASDF**.